# Sort ElasticSearch results by a custom Compare function on field

Tags: python, sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

If I want to fetch Driver data from elastic sorted on rating where rating could be `["good", "ok", "bad"]`, how to write the query which can help me get data in sorted order considering good > ok > bad

Ex sorted response list:

```
[{
    "name": "driver1",
    "rating": "good"
},
{
    "name": "driver3",
    "rating": "good"
},
{
    "name": "driver2",
    "rating": "ok"
},
{
    "name": "driver4",
    "rating": "bad"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For changing score value based on a field in your index you can use script score query, your query should look like below example:

```
GET /my-index-2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all":{}
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "if (doc['rating.keyword'].value == 'good'){2} else if(doc['rating.keyword'].value == 'ok') {1} else if(doc['rating.keyword'].value == 'bad') {0}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more information about script score query you can check Elastic official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html).